# On JQuery AJAX POST...request failed: URI too long (longer than 8190)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, post

I got the error:

`request failed: URI too long (longer than 8190)`

I've seen other posts on StackOverflow for this one. Those posts recommend:

- Not changing Apache settings (agree)
- Using post, not get
- Not using `jsonp` with post

I'm using jQuery's AJAX to POST:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: paras,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(ret){callback(ret);}
    });
```

It's my impression you can use json just not jsonp. Correct? If so, why might I still be getting the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try setting proccessData to false.

From the docs:

> By default, data passed in to the data option as an object
>   (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and
>   transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a
>   DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

so to prevent the data being added to the url:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    dataType: "application/json",
    data: paras,
    type: "POST",
    proccessData: false, // this is true by default
    success: function(ret){callback(ret);}
});
```

Honestly, I thought this was automatic, but since your url is too long it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when using jQuery to submit large forms, and was able to solve it by adding [this plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

For example, using the following code to submit the form after adding the plugin resolved the issue for me:

```
    $(formSelectorHere).ajaxSubmit({
        url: myURL,
        type: 'post',
        contentType: "multipart/form-data",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
        function(data) {
            //success code here//
        }
    });
```

If you're not using this to submit a form, this may not be relevant to you and won't solve your problem, but that's the most common situation where this issue appears, so I figured it was worth mentioning. (The plugin should also be able to submit a form using JSON, but haven't personally tested it).